# How to remove Postgres extension

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

I enabled extension **pg_stat_statements** for PostgreSQL

```
create EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

How can I stop using extension **pg_stat_statements** in PostgreSQL 9.x?

Even [original documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgstatstatements.html) does not contain any examples.

Answer (score 60):

```
DROP EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

Comment: What if the extension is something you install with `yum` or `apt-get` and add to `shared_preload_libraries` such as pg_cron? Is removing it with package manager and deleting it form `shared_preload_libraries` needed?

Answer (score 11):

```
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS <extension name>;

CREATE EXTENSION <extension name>;
```