# Error "public.powa_take_snapshot()" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am observing this error in the log of my PostgreSQL 12:

```
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:LOG:  POWA connected to database powa
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:ERROR:  query returned more than one row
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:HINT:  Make sure the query returns a single row, or use LIMIT 1.
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function powa_take_snapshot(integer) line 31 at SQL statement
        SQL statement "SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot()"
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:LOG:  background worker "powa" (PID 34049) exited with exit code 1
```

I have tried to restart the DB but the error appears again. If I launch the SELECT statement "[local] postgres@postgres=# SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot();" I get this error:

```
"ERROR: function public.powa_take_snapshot() does not exist".
LINE 1: SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot()
               ^
TIP: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add an explicit type conversion".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am a bit confused about what exactly is your question: do you expect POWA to connect, or not?

Comment: @fvu What I want is to remove the error that appears in the log, as this prevents me from executing a pg_basebackup on my DB.

Comment: The way to remove the error is to *fix the code* in then function `powa_take_snapshot(integer_parameter)`. But without the function code that is impossible to do - cannot fix what you cannot see. You need to post that code and explain what it does. Including table definition(s) and sample data would be useful. Finally with `SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot()` you get the *No function matches ...* error because you did not provide the required parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your system at one point had the PoWA tool installed ( https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html ) but that installation seems at least broken, as the powa_take_snapshot function seems absent. However, the fact that it gets called seems to indicate that the *powa_archivist* extension is still active.  Check by listing installed extensions) [Using psql how do I list extensions installed in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799956/using-psql-how-do-i-list-extensions-installed-in-a-database)_

Now, as me mentioning PoWA didn't seem to ring a bell with you I assume that it's something either a predecessor installed some day, or that it's so long ago that you don't remember, and getting rid of it is the best solution, like explained here: [How to remove Postgres extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455992/how-to-remove-postgres-extension)

Have a look at [their github](https://github.com/powa-team) to be able to make an informed decision.